# Do I have to pass the dataset both to the loader and the RandomSampler?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

This is my code

```
  def train_dataloader(self):
        if self._is_weighted_sampler:
            weights = list(self.label_weight_by_name.values())
            sampler = torch.utils.data.sampler.WeightedRandomSampler(
                torch.tensor(weights), len(weights)
            )
        else:
            sampler = torch.utils.data.RandomSampler(self._train_dataset)
        return DataLoader(self._train_dataset, batch_size=self._batch_size, shuffle=True, sampler=sampler)
```

Notice in the case of Weighted sampler, it doesn't require the dataset, but RandomSampler does.

In the RandomSampler case, it means the dataset is passed twice.

I must be missing something about how this is to be used, please correct me.

Comment: It seems that if you set `shuffle=True` it will automatically use the `RandomSampler` class, so in your else statement you could just have `sampler=None` (see https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py#L348)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it looks like you're correct about this discrepancy; there doesn't seem to be an immediately obvious reason why one call needs the dataset object and the other does not. Per the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.RandomSampler) the function prototypes are:

> ```
> torch.utils.data.RandomSampler(data_source, replacement=False, num_samples=None, generator=None)
> ```

Digging into the [source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/data/sampler.html#RandomSampler), one sees that `data_source` is never indexed by `Random_Sampler` and is only ever used as `len(data_source)`. This object yields indices, and the dataset object is only used to determine the length of the data.

> ```
> torch.utils.data.WeightedRandomSampler(weights, num_samples, replacement=True, generator=None)
> ```

Randomly samples weights from `weights` (which i.e. should be set up to have the same number of elements as your dataset) and returns a set of indices, which then must be separately used to index into the dataset object.

Perhaps the rationale of the developers was "in the case of a `WeightedRandomSampler`, the user must define a weight for each item in the data source. In the case of `RandomSampler`, all of the weights are one, so rather than defining a vector of ones the user can simply pass the dataset object itself." Why they wouldn't just pass the length of the dataset as an integer to `RandomSampler` is beyond me.